# 'static void' as decl-specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++

Following code compiles fine with clang. I wanted to know if the C++ standard is okay with this.

```
class A {
  static void x; // #1
  static const void x; // #2
  static volatile void x; // #3
};
```

In my opinion none of the declarations are valid. The [perenial C++ standard validation suite](http://www.peren.com/pages/cppvs_set.htm)
has such one such test (#1) and clang (v3.4) fails in that.

Although, if I remove static from #1 then clang reports error as expected.

I looked at the standard and I found one paragraph on static data members (9.4.2-2) which says:

> 2 The declaration of a static data member in its class deﬁnition is not a 
>       deﬁnition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualiﬁed void. ...

As I understand this line disqualifies #2 and #3 as invalid but not sure about #1. Are there any more details related to declaration with static storage class that should rule out #1?

Thanks,

Comment: this is a clang extension. I am pretty sure I read the commit about it in the past.

Comment: It is possible. In what context this extension could possibly be useful though?

Comment: I guess if you are instantiating a `template<class T> class` with a member variable `T x`, it might be useful not to break if `T = void` straight away.

Comment: Actually I am not even sure allowing `void` to be a complete (singleton) type would be a problem, maybe `sizeof(void)`, `new void` or the various `void*` rules would bite you somehow.

Comment: But when there is no template, allowing such a syntax is not good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not allowed, precisely because of the paragraph you quote. Notice, that the term "cv-qualified" in the paragraph you quote includes non-qualification. Per paragraph 3.9.3/10 of the C++11 Standard:

> In this International Standard, the notation `cv` (or `cv1`, `cv2`, etc.), used in the description of types, represents
>   an arbitrary set of cv-qualifiers, i.e., one of {`const`}, {`volatile`}, {`const`, `volatile`}, **or the empty set.**

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. Now I'm wondering how difficult is it to fix this in clang. Or I should wait for it to be fixed.

Comment: @AdityaKumar: Unfortunately I do not know - I have never tried to delve into Clang's source code :(